# border-top cannot be seen for some reason

Tags: html, css

border-top cut off by the top of page??

I have tried setting the margin-top of the h2 element but it was still the same result.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  background: #222;
}

#heading-background {
  background: #55d6aa;
  height: 50px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

h2 {
  color: #222;
  padding: 0 0 0 14px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 20px;
  font-size: 28px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5em;
  display: inline;
  border: 2px solid #222;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div id="heading">
  <div id="heading-background">
    <div id="heading-text">
      <h2>TODO</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: inline-block, not inline

Comment: the duplicate deals with margin and the same apply for padding/border (will find the other duplicates)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'm relatively new to the web development scene so I do not have much experience. Thanks for the help, I get it now!

Answer (score 2):

This will do the work     `h2 { display: inline-block; }`